# How to find these UserPermissions in sandbox?

Tags: salesforcedx, profile, custom-profile, user-profile

I am seeing below unwanted UserPermissions in the GIT branch, and unfortunately it went to sandbox as well through CICD. I would like to remove these assigned permissions from 4 profiles as profile cleanup activity in sandbox. If someone has any insight on what is the label corresponds to each UserPermission in profile section to view/modify it. Below were the CustomPermissions impacted on 4 profiles.

UserPermissions on System-Admin Profile:

1. CreateContentSpace
2. CreateLtngTempFolder
3. ManageHubConnections
4. ManagePropositions
5. ManageRecommendationStrategies
6. ManageSubscriptions
7. ManageSandboxes
8. ModifyDataClassification
9. PrivacyDataAccess
10. SubscribeDashboardRolesGrps
11. SubscribeReportRolesGrps
12. TraceXdsQueries
13. TransactionalEmailSend
14. ViewFlowUsageAndFlowEventData
15. ViewUserPII

UserPermissions on API User Profile

1. AccessCMC
2. CreatePackaging
3. InstallPackaging
4. PublishPackaging
5. SendExternalEmailAvailable
6. TransactionalEmailSend

UserPermissions on Custom Profile

1. ArchiveArticles
2. EditKnowledge
3. EditTranslation
4. ManageKnowledge
5. ManageKnowledgeImportExport
6. PublishArticles
7. PublishTranslation
8. SendExternalEmailAvailable
9. ShareInternalArticles
10. TransactionalEmailSend
11. SubmitForTranslation

UserPermissions on ReadOnly Profile

1. ContentAdministrator
2. CustomizeApplication
3. ManageContentPermissions
4. ManageContentProperties
5. ManageContentTypes
6. ManageCustomPermissions
7. ManagePackageLicenses
8. ManageTranslation
9. ResetPasswords

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Rather than try to research all these, just remove them from the profile XML, then re-deploy. This should fix the files without needing to use the UI. However, please note that some permissions may have been added by the Winter '20 update, and standard profiles cannot generally be modified in terms of system permissions. This is why most organizations opt to use custom profiles to begin with.

Alternatively, you can run the following code to get (most) permissions:

```
for(sobjectfield field: profile.sobjectType.getDescribe().fields.getmap().values()) {
    describefieldresult result = field.getDescribe();
    System.debug('Field: '+result.getName()+' Label: '+result.getLabel());
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer brother. Indeed, Perfect Solution :)